# Create new struct pointer and emplace map

Tags: c++

I have a question.

```
struct sInfos
{
    const char* name;
    int8_t       id;
    int8_t       department;
};

std::map<int8_t, sInfos*> map_try;

const auto& info = new sInfos;
info->name = "asd"; 
info->id = 0;
info->department = 0;
map_try.emplace(id(parametre), info);
//delete info; // HERE
```

When I coded new register I'm using `new sInfos` but I'm not deleting because when I write  `delete info` or `unique_ptr` or `make_unique` I'm having trouble (map gets mixed up (runtime)). This codes have any leaks? Sorry for bad English, thanks everyone.

Comment: Yes it does. `new` without `delete` is a memory leak, plain and simple. This is why C++ developers don't like using `new`. Modern C++ is mostly `unique_ptr` and other container types. In your case, you really don't even need a pointer; just do `std::map<std::string, sInfos>`. (`std::string` because WhozCraig's comment also makes an excellent point)

Comment: I strongly suspect your resulting map here won't be what you intend. a `const char *` key without a customer map comparator for order is *not* going to order (and this key) the map the way you think it will. The ordering as-presented will be based on global memory address ordering of pointer values; not string value ordering. If the former was your intent, so be it, but it would be as odd as it is senseless.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo thanks for comment! Example codes is true? (just example so this is shit) https://godbolt.org/z/WWaefdx93

Comment: For readability, if you use raw pointers, you should write `auto *info = new sInfos;` instead of `const auto& info = new sInfos;`. If you really want to be sure that the pointer is not updated afterwards, then `auto* const info = new sInfos;` would more clearly show the intend.

Comment: @WayneCox That looks good. I still recommend reading up on [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and using it instead of `const char*` (the former behaves more intuitively in a lot of situations). But your linked code will not leak memory anymore.

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of completeness here is how it can be with string and unique_ptr

with 2 examples of placing into map

```
struct sInfos
{
    std::string name;
    int         id;
    int8_t       department;
};

std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<sInfos>> map_try;

// create directly into the map, then load data
map_try.emplace(0, std::make_unique<sInfos>());
map_try[0]->id = 0;
map_try[0]->name = "asd";
map_try[0]->department = 0;

// create first, load data, then put in map
auto info = std::make_unique<sInfos>();
info->id = 1;
info->name = "dfgh";
info->department = 42;
map_try.insert({ 1, std::move(info) });
```